# How can I determine what changes are unmerged in a branch in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: git, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017 (using a git repository managed by VS2017), sometimes when trying to delete a branch, it gives an error message that there are unmerged changes.

How can I get a list of these unmerged changes to review?

I would very much prefer to avoid the inscrutable git command line if at all possible.

Comment: If i understand your question correctly you can view it by Team Explorer->Changes

Comment: @WojtekT These are all branches with no uncommitted changes *in that branch*.   So the changes list is blank.   But they cannot be deleted due to unmerged changes with master--I am trying to determine what those are, so I can review whether they should be merged or not.

Comment: create pull request from branch to master and you'll see unmerged 
commitments

Comment: or just merge locally

Comment: btw, I know you don't want to use command line, but it's very easy: git diff branch master

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is there to let you know that the branch you are deleting has not been merged into the remote master branch, so you will lose* the contents of the branch if you delete it.

**Comparing Branches with Master Branch**

First you need to checkout the feature branch you want to compare:

[image]

Then check to see if the feature is up to date by looking for the origin master branch in the branch history:

1. Right click the branch and select "View History..."
2. Make sure Local, Remote, and Tags are all visible by checking their respective buttons
3. Look for origin/master in the branch heads marked to the right (not your local master)

[image]

If you can't find the origin/master branch, your branch is out of date and you'll need to merge origin/master into your branch:

1. Right click on "master" under "remotes/origin" and complete the dialog to merge from origin master into your local branch
2. Click the refresh icon in the history panel
3. Locate the origin/master branch

[image]

Now we can compare our local branch to the origin/master branch:

1. Click on your feature branch
2. Ctrl+Click on the origin/master branch
3. Right click and select "Compare Commits..."

[image]

The list of changes will display in the Team panel. Double Clicking on any file will open a side-by-side diff view of the file.

[image]

Here I've marked the commits on master in green and the commits that only exist on your branch in red (the Initial Commit is technically on both). This method will show the combined changes of the three commits marked here in red.

[image]

If you're OK with losing* the changes, you can force the branch to delete.

*lose is a relative term in git, as there is a considerable window where you can undo (almost) any action you make in a git repo

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ This isn't part of the answer proper, so I'll add it here. Don't be afraid of the git command line. It's got a bit of a steep learning curve (like a brick wall) but it's a brick wall around a treasure trove of functionality. Dabbling in it here and there, even simple things like making a commit or creating a branch, can help to demystify it so if you ever get into a situation where you NEED to use it, you won't have to approach it like it's the Rabbit of Caerbannog.

Comment: The git command line is so actively user hostile that I use it only as a last resort when desperation overcomes reason.    Unfortunately, the answer you linked shows how to compare the the content of two commits in the history of the same branch.  I need to know what is unmerged between two branches, so i can decide whether to merge or force the delete.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ You can use the same method to compare two commits on different branches as well. By selecting the head of your branch and the head of the master branch (or better origin/master) you can see the difference between the two branches.

Comment: You do realize how absolutely impenetrable the process you just described is to a casual user?  I am a program director, I code maybe 25% of my time at best, and deal with git only as a sideline in that time.  I don't know or want to or have to to research  what the MD5 codes are for the heads of branches, compare those, then try to find the files in visual studio.  Is there a sane way for mere mortals?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not trying to be confusing, let's try another tack. Are you using a web based central server for your git repositories? GitHub, BitBucket, TFS, etc?

Comment: I use the Microsoft one.  Not sure all the local branches are synced up though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153505/discussion-between-lightbender-and-saj14saj).